# listview with collection of integers

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview

How do I bind a ListView to a Collection of integers?

Answer (score 3):

This could have been answered with just a cursory google search, but...

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewNumbers">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Number" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And in code you could do this:

```
listViewNumbers.ItemsSource = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you might want to have an all-XAML solution:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
            <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>3</sys:Int32>
        </x:Array>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>
</ListView>
```

Strictly speaking that is not a binding though, but if you define collection in XAML it is normally static, so binding does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ItemSource property of the ListView.